# Font Awesome Freeのライセンスについて

Tags: ライセンス, font

Font Awesome Freeのライセンスについて質問です。
参考：https://fontawesome.com/license/free

上記URLの記載によると、Webフォントとして使う場合は、"Downloaded Font Awesome Free files already contain embedded comments with sufficient attribution" とのことで、そのまま使えば良いと思うのですが、pngなどの画像にして使う場合はどのように著作権表記するのが望ましいでしょうか。
自サイトにリンク集のようなページを設けて、Font Awesomeへのリンクを貼れば良いでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

参考ページには、アイコンは[CC BY 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/)のライセンスが付与されていると明記されていますから、これに従えば問題ありません。

CC BY 4.0は著作権表記が必要なライセンスですから、原則として**著作権表記は必要**です。
ただ、質問者さんが引用されているように、フォントファイルやJSファイル等には予め必要な著作権表記が含まれているためそのまま使用すればOKということになります。

png画像としてアイコンを使用する場合は、それ単体だと著作権表記がされていませんから、別途に著作権表記をする必要があります。

著作権表記の方法はCC BY 4.0に従えばOKです。一番簡単な方法は、著作権者（Font Awesome）を明記し、[Font Awesomeへのライセンスページへのリンク](https://fontawesome.com/license/free)を貼り、さらに[CC BY 4.0ライセンス](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/)へのリンクを貼ることです。

どこにこれを記載するかについては、サイト内に「権利表記」のようなタイトルのページを設けてそこに記載するとよいと思います。法律家ではないので確実なことは申し上げられませんが、このような手法は大手のアプリ等でも行われているため問題ないかと思います。

Comment: 差し支えなければ、参考にしたいので、その大手アプリの名称を教えていただけないでしょうか。

Comment: とりあえず任天堂の「Nintendo Switch Online」やLINE社の「LINE」がこのような手法を取っていることを確認しました。

Answer (score 1):

参照サイトの右側に「してもOKなこと」「してはNGなこと」リストがそれぞれありますが、png画像での利用は

> **Dos (OK項目)**
>   - Embed FA Free in documents. (e.g. .pdf, .doc, etc.)

に含まれるのではないでしょうか。

唯一のNG項目が「(Font Awesomeの)名前を自分で作成した成果物に付けてはいけない」=「紛らわしい名前を付けてはダメ」なので、この点だけ気を付ければ問題ないと読み取れます。

Comment: 著作権表記は必要ないということでしょうか。

Comment: 不明瞭な点があれば直接問い合わせて確認してもらった方が確実かなと思います (ホームページに連絡先があります)。

Comment: わかりました問い合わせてみます。